# Does tensorflow.js mobilenet model.classify work better with square images?

Tags: tensorflow.js

In Python code I see that images given to MobileNet are 224x224 while the Tensorflow.js version seems to work with any size or aspect ratio. For non-square images does it stretch them or add white or transparent pixels to produce square input with the aspect ratio of the image maintained? If it does stretch it to become square should one do some image manipulation before using model.classify?

https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/mobilenet#making-a-classification doesn't say anything about this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirements for images to be square. Using non square images will achieve the same result. Maybe the reason why some neural networks such as mobilenet use square images are for operation such as convolution where the kernel is chosen most of the time as square.

To use mobilenet for classification, the image needs to be reshape to a shape of `[224, 224, 3]` which is the input size of the network. Methods such as `.resizeBilinear`, `resizeNearestNeighbor`, ... will achieve that very purpose. Obviously transforming a non square image to a square image will distort the image. But those algorithms use the technique of [anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing) to make up for the distorsion.

But the distorsion of the input image is the less thing one need to be concerned with. Actually, a good model prediction should be invariant to such distorsion, because the trained data were so much distorted and augmented with noise so that the model can generalize well.

Comment: I'm also using `model.infer` together with KNN's  `.predictClass` and it seems to work well despite the fact that the images are all different sizes and ratios. Would it work even better if I used the methods (.`resizeBilinear`, `resizeNearestNeighbor`, ...) you suggested?

Comment: Well, it might depend on your data